# How SessionFactory internally works in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I made 4 files:

1.UserDetail.java
2.UserDTO1.java
3.hibernate.cfg.xml
4.UserDTO1.hbm.xml

In **UserDetail.java** I made SessionFactory's Implemented class object:

```
Session Factory factory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Now the control goes to hibernate ( but I wanted to know the order whether connection is established first or the mapping resource="**UserDTO1.hbm.xml**" is executed first )

Then in **UserDTO1.hbm.xml**  how the control is going to DTO file . And when,

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

in configuration file will be executed.

I want to know the **flow of execution** how all these things are going on.

Answer (score 0):

In **cnf.xml**, it first establishes a connection then the control goes to **hbm.xml**.